# Cypress - Add custom header for all XHR requests

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, cypress

I notice that `X-CSRFToken` header is getting removed between tests, for all the XHR requests that triggered from application under test. I'm not sure to preserve this header, as I'm already preserving the Cookies through `Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('sessionid', 'csrftoken')`

Hence, I thought of appending the custom header `X-CSRFToken` to all the XHR requests from the application. Here is the script I used, where I'm fetching the `csrftoken` from cookies and setting to custom header.

```
cy.server({
   onAnyRequest: function(route, proxy) {
        proxy.xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', cy.getCookie('csrftoken'));
   }
})
```

Here, I'm getting the below error,

```
Argument of type '{ onAnyRequest: (route: any, proxy: any) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<ServerOptions>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'onAnyRequest' does not exist in type 'Partial<ServerOptions>'.
```

I'm expecting any working solution to this approach or a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to make everyone aware, I communicated with makers of `Cypress` and got to know that the stubbing of outgoing request is under development and can be tracked under - https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/687

Answer (score 10):

Now `cy.server` is deprecated, you can use `cy.intercept` instead:

```js
cy.intercept('http://api.company.com/', (req) => {
  req.headers['authorization'] = `token ${token}`
})
```

More info in the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Usage).

Comment: works perfect, thank you! Optionally, you can set e.g. `'GET'` or `'POST'` as the first parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Run your code in a beforeEach statement.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.server({
        onAnyRequest: function(route, proxy) {
           proxy.xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', cy.getCookie('csrftoken'));
       }
    })
});
```

Comment: cy.server is deprecated :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `onRequest` instead of `onAnyRequest`. [Here's the documentation for `cy.server` options](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/server.html#Arguments)

Comment: I did through `onRequest` as well. But, what I hear from Mr.Gleb Bahmutov is that this feature is not available in @cypress right now.