# Cypress adding token to all requests headers

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, e2e-testing, cypress-intercept

I'm testing a website that returns token in body from login request. Then all the requests made after we logged in use this token value in header.

I made a custom cypress command that logs in by sending a POST request, but i can't get how to make it push the token to all requests inside my app during test run.

This is a command:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url:'site/login',
        form: true,
        body:{
            "username":creds.login,
            "password":creds.password
        }
    }).then((resp) => {
        const token = resp.body.token
        cy.intercept('*', (req) => {
            req.headers['token'] = token
        })
    })
})
```

In the part after `.then((resp) => {...` i'm trying to intercept all requests and add token to their headers. I can see that requests are intercepted but i'm still logged out from my app.

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937793/cypress-add-custom-header-for-all-xhr-requests) solution, but also didn't work.

How can i get token from response body and add it to all requests in cypress?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends if the requests are coming from the web page itself or if you are testing an API that needs the token.

`cy.intercept()` will not catch `cy.request()` calls made from the test, only calls made from the web page.

For API tests, you would need to set the token in `cy.request()` explicitly.

The other problem may be where the intercept is set up. It is probably better to store the token globally and set the intercept in the test or another `beforeEach()`.

Here's a general pattern that may suit.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url:'site/login',
    form: true,
    body:{
      "username":creds.login,
      "password":creds.password
    }
  }).then((resp) => {
    const token = resp.body.token
    Cypress.env('token', token)     // save the token for use elsewhere
  })
})

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.login()
})

it('testing web page requests with token', () => {
  cy.intercept('*', (req) => {
    req.headers['token'] = Cypress.env('token')
    //or
    req.headers['authorization'] = Cypress.env('token')  // check you have the right header
  })
  cy.visit('/')
  ...
})

it('testing API with cy.request() and using token', () => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url:'site/api/...',
    headers: {
      token: Cypress.env('token')
    }
  }).then((resp) => {
    ...
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, that worked perfectly for `cy.request()`, but still had issues with  the requests coming from webpage.

I manage to deal with, it turns out that i not only needed to add token to headers, but also set it to `localStorage` alongside with another params that are setted after we press the login button in UI.

So it worked like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url:'/site/login',
        form: true,
        body:{
            "username":creds.login,
            "password":creds.password
        }
    }).then((resp) => {
        const token = resp.body.token
        Cypress.env('token', token)
        window.localStorage.setItem('item1', `{"a":"1", "b":"2", "token":${JSON.stringify(token)}}`)
        window.localStorage.setItem('item2', 'value2')
        window.localStorage.setItem('item3', 'value3')
    })
```